# Use an Access form while a report is being generated?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to create a progress bar for an Access form. I have everything figured out on the progress bar end. The problem I am facing is that The pop up form with the progress bar needs to repaint itself each time the width is increased. However, while a report is being generated. (The query is running) Everything else freezes. Therefore the progress bar cannot repaint itself until after the query is complete.

Comment: Do you have multiple action queries to run before opening the report or is it just a report based on one query that takes a long time to open?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to use Access' in-built [progress bar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb258150%28v=office.12%29.aspx), using SysCmd.